pytest selenium: 2 different element window present for for redirection
enter image description here        chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")  # Allows attaching DevTools

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

    driver.get("http://localhost:8080")

    element = driver.find_element("id", "items")

    element.click()

once we click on element it will navinate to another page, where i am trying to find out another element that i can't found.
when i did it mannually i saw 2 different inspect element as it present in screenshot.
I wanted to find element from 2nd element window.

You need to switch to the New window opened before doing any interaction.
Ref documentation

there is only one window present in driver.window_handles

Can you kindly share a screenshot (of the whole screen) so that everyone can understand what happens when you click on the first element? Maybe that will help clear things up. Thanks!

Then,  Please share the screenshot of DOM you inspected and code what you trying to do

Got the answer, was trying to add automation electron js desktop app.
It work with below code:
   options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

    app_path = '<app_path>'
    chromedriver_path = "<chromedriver_path>"

    options.binary_location = app_path
    cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(chromedriver_path), options=options)
    cls.driver.implicitly_wait(10)

